# Null Pointer exception at Bundle bundle=new Bundle();

Tags: android

I was used the below code in fragments and its showing null pointer exception at bundle variable while using putString.

```
Bundle bundle_from= new Bundle();
bundle_from=saveState();
bundle_from=getArguments();
bundle_from.putString("type", type_holder); // Here null pointer exception


MileageTripGpsActivity_fragment_obj.setArguments(bundle_from);
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep changing what `bundle_from` is, so even though you create one, you're replacing it.

`getArguments()` is `null`, which is why it is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Before you put each element into bundle check weather it is null not.